# How to turn picture into link in jquery?

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

```
<script>
        $(function() {
            var BV = new $.BigVideo();
            BV.init();
            if (Modernizr.touch) {
                BV.show('/pics/googlePlusCover.jpg');
            } else {
                BV.show('/video.mp4',{ambient:true});
            }
        });

</script>
```

I am trying to make this `BV.show('/pics/googlePlusCover.jpg');` a clickable link. Unfortunately I do not know how!
I am sure this is an easy task for somebody, who is more in the know.

Thank you so much for your help already!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an image, say:

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" />
```

use:

```
$("img").wrap("<a href='http://www.google.com'></a>")
```

which will wrap the image inside `<a>` elements, and make it a link. If there are multiple of them, use `wrapAll`.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/GmxVB/)**

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! You already helped me a lot! Now i just need to figure out how to give this BV.show('/pics/googlePlusCover.jpg'); some kind of id or img tag.